# Finding the marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

$f_{XY}(x,y)=C e^{-(x^2+y^2-xy)}$ with $x,y \in R$

I need to find the marginal pdfs. I am quite struck by this question.

I tried this way -

$f_X(x)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(x,y)dy $

I have $Ce^{-x}[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}  +\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{xy}]$

Now, the first part inside the bracket evaluates to $\sqrt \pi$ (Gaussian integral)

The second part worries me, since the limits are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notice that, for a fixed $x$, the exponent $$-(y^2 - xy + x^2)$$ is a quadratic function of $y$, and completing the square gives us $$-((y-x/2)^2 + 3x^2/4).$$  Consequently, as $|y| \to \infty$, this exponent always tends to $-\infty$, hence the integrand tends to $0$ in either direction.  This tells you that your approach of splitting the integrand is not correct.

Rather, we should observe that $$f_X(x) = Ce^{-3x^2/4} \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y-x/2)^2} \, dy,$$ and that the value of the integral over the real line is the same for any fixed $x$.  This gives the marginal density for $X$, and the marginal density of $Y$ is handled similarly.  The constant $C$ is determined by integrating either marginal density and equating it to $1$.